# how to add class to the ul returned by wp_list_bookmarks

Tags: get-bookmarks

wp_list_bookmarks returns HTML that has a `ul` with classes `xoxo blogroll`. I'd like to add another class to that ul, but can't seem to find an elegant way to do so.

wp_list_bookmarks does accept an argument "class", but that is applied to the li, not the ul. Is there some argument I'm missing? Or is there a hook I can hook onto and add a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a filter `'wp_list_bookmarks'` for the complete markup. You can use it:

```
add_filter( 'wp_list_bookmarks', 'wpse40213_new_classes', 10, 1 );

function wpse40213_new_classes( $html )
{
    return str_replace( "class='xoxo blogroll'", "class='my_bookmarks blogroll'", $html );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking in the direction of string replacing. But why should I do it with a filter? What's the difference between that, and doing: `$str=wp_list_bookmarks('echo=0'); echo str_replace( "class='xoxo blogroll'", "class='my_bookmarks blogroll'", $str);` ?

Comment: There is no big difference. The filter will run always, no matter where and how often you call `wp_list_bookmarks()`. Plus, a child theme could remove or replace the filter.